# How to get all documents in elasticsearch index using "*" in simple_query_string

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am passing the `*` into the query to fetch all fields in index using the `simple_query_string` script, but it returns only an empty result. Kindly guide me to solve this situation. The formed query is:

> {"query":{"simple_query_string":{"query":"*","fields":["_all"]}},"from":0,"size":5}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is found in the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html):

> `*` at the end of a term signifies a prefix query

`*` is not a regular wildcard. You can only use it at the end of a token, e.g. `exampl*` matches `exampleword`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all available documents there's a [dedicated query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-all-query.html) for that :

> { "match_all": {} }

For [wildcard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) style match you would use :

> {
>       "wildcard" : { "user" : "ki*y" }
>   }

Check more info on wildcard queries [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_wildcard_and_regexp_queries.html).